# Esp8266 header file code interpreat

Tags: microcontroller, c, esp8266, c++

Currently I am working in a project on esp8266 and before getting into the project I started to read the library and in a section I found something which has no meaning to me. I need help on that

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define ESP_ERROR_CHECK(x) do {                                         \
    esp_err_t rc = (x);                                             \
    (void) sizeof(rc);   //why there is void return                                           \
} while(0);// why do-while loop with 0 as parameter 
#else
#define ESP_ERROR_CHECK(x) do {                                         \
    esp_err_t rc = (x);                                             \
    if (rc != ESP_OK) {                                             \
        _esp_error_check_failed(rc, __FILE__, __LINE__,             \
                                __ASSERT_FUNC, #x);                 \
     }                                                               \
 } while(0);
#endif
```

[Link to the head file (git hub)](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp32/include/esp_err.h)

Look forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your questions are the ones added as a comment to the code:

The code defines two version of a macro. The first version is used in release code. It executes `x` withouth checking for errors.

The second version is used in debug builds of the code; it executes `x` and checks the result for an error status. If an error has occurred, it prints an error message and stops execution.

The code:

```
(void) sizeof(rc);
```

is most likely used to prevent a warning about the unused variable `rc`. `(void)` is required to prevent yet another warning or error because `sizeof(rc)` is an expression and not a statement.

The block `do { ... } while(0);` is used to make the macro behave like a single statement. Without the *while* statement, the following block would not compile:

```
if (ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start()))
    abc();
else
    def();
```

At least that's the intention. Unfortunately, it's not properly done. The semicolon at the end should be removed.

Comment: As per my knowledge multiple lines or your words a single block is made using '\' inside a macro definition, then why do-while. I never saw such kind of  practice before

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan - Your question / doubt is answered in detail, in these topics from Stack Overflow & Code Review: https://stackoverflow.com/q/257418/ || https://stackoverflow.com/q/9495962/ || https://stackoverflow.com/q/923822/ || https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1679/

Comment: I got my answer but the said the main purpose of using do-while is ';' but here not the case. And this library works fine

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan - "*but here not the case*" Yes, it really is :-) Without using that `do {} while(0)` technique, it affects the syntax of how you must use the macro. "*this library works fine*" Yes of course, because it uses that technique! I think perhaps we are not understanding each other. :-( Unfortunately I don't have time to explain it better than those answers that I already linked for you. Perhaps someone else will have more time to help you.